# Probability of Two Suits within Three cards, within 4 cards

Tags: combinatorics

I am trying to calculate what is the probability of the 3 random cards of 52-pack containing at least two of the same suit.

I am also trying to do the same for the four card variant (so, the successful outcome would be all 4 are of the different suits).

With three cards, my calculation is as follows:

1st card is random and doesn't matter what suit it is.
The second one must be one of the remaining 39 of 51 and the third one must be one of the remaining 26 of 50.

So the total p_flush draw (3 cards) = 1-52/52*39/51*26/50.

With four cards, its the same as with previous example, but with one last addition:

p_flush draw (4 cards) = 1-52/52*39/51*26/50*13/49

Is that all correct?

And I would appreciate if someone shares the idea how to deal with such problems by using COMBIN function.

Comment: Your calculations are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answers are right. Here is a different presentation but same idea.

P(3 cards with at least 2 of the same suit)
$= ({4 \choose 2} * 2!*13*{13 \choose 2} + {4\choose1}*{13 \choose 3})/{52 \choose 3}$

Comment: Would you mind please to walk me through the each of the number of the equation?

Comment: The numerator consists of 2 terms. The 1st term is to count 2 in same suit of 3 cards. We first choose 2 suits from 4, 1 suit of 2 cards and 1 suit of  1 card. Because, say, 2 clubs and 1 spade are different from 2 spades and 1 club, so the number is multiplied by $2!$. After that 1 card of 1 suit has $13$ outcomes, and the other 2 cards have ${13 \choose 2}$. The 2nd term is to count all 3 cards in same suit. We first choose 1 from 4 suits, then choose 3 cards from ${13 \choose 3}$ outcomes.

Answer (score 2):

Making use of what you call 'COMBIN' function:

$$1-\binom{4}{3}\binom{13}{1}\binom{13}{1}\binom{13}{1}\binom{13}{0}\binom{52}{3}^{-1}$$ if you draw $3$ cards.

$$1-\binom{4}{4}\binom{13}{1}\binom{13}{1}\binom{13}{1}\binom{13}{1}\binom{52}{4}^{-1}$$ if you draw $4$ cards.